# Do I have to use CoreData if I want to make a typical Intelligence Test app that depends on the answer has a different result?

Tags: objective-c, core-data

I want to implement an app that is a test of intelligence. Do I have to use CoreData, or what alternatives do I have?

If so, do you have a good CoreData tutorial or similar reference?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CoreData is just a persistance layer.  You can store your data in whatever medium works best for you.

- Hardcoded in classes
- In plists
- In flat files

CoreData is nice because it gives you the full power of a relational database behind a set of abstraction classes that work well in an object orientated environment, but you never have to use it.

For learning CoreData I found the Marcus Zarra [book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1934356328) to be good.